Flutter Build.gradle doesn't seem right
I'm new to Flutter and currently exploring how to integrate Firebase into my project. As I've been going through various tutorials, I've noticed that the build.gradle file often looks different from what I have in my setup. Could someone help me understand the common discrepancies and how to reconcile them?
It's a bit confusing to figure out the necessary changes to align my file with the updated standards for Firebase integration. Any guidance or resources that could help clarify these differences would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!My build.gradle looks like this
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Looked in different forums, didn't find anything
